# Office js/Scriptlab - excel beta api data validation list fails with "api not found" error, but excel version is correct

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I am trying to create a basic dropdown in excel using Office js beta api.

https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

I am using the example provided in the below documentation for "List validation rule type"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-data-validation

The below code adds data validation rule of type "list" to a range "B2:B5" in the current active sheet:

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B5");   
    var nameSourceRange = "Entry1, Entry2, Entry3"

    range.dataValidation.rule = {
        list: {
            inCellDropDown: true,
            source: nameSourceRange
        }
    };

    return context.sync();
})
```

I have imported the "beta" api but the data validation rule fails with the below error. The "Script Lab" official example of "Data Validation" also fails with the same error. Non-beta functionalities are working fine for me and there is no issue with download of the script files from cdn.

*"ApiNotFound: The API you are trying to use could not be found. It may be available in a newer version of Excel."*

Debug info:

```
code 
"ApiNotFound" 

errorLocation 
"Range.dataValidation" 

message 
"The API you are trying to use could not be found. It may be available in a newer version of Excel."
```

Stacktrace from scriptlab:

```
Error: The API you are trying to use could not be found. It may be available in a newer version of Excel.
   at r (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:239022) [<root>]
   at i.prototype.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:221647) [<root>]
   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:219868) [<root>]
   at Zone.prototype.run (https://script-lab.azureedge.net/bundles/polyfills.e10fc062eb880ff38340.bundle.js:1:80212) [<root> => <root>]
   at Anonymous function (https://script-lab.azureedge.net/bundles/polyfills.e10fc062eb880ff38340.bundle.js:1:77429) [<root>]
   at Zone.prototype.runTask (https://script-lab.azureedge.net/bundles/polyfills.e10fc062eb880ff38340.bundle.js:1:80903) [<root> => <root>]
   at drainMicroTaskQueue (https://script-lab.azureedge.net/bundles/polyfills.e10fc062eb880ff38340.bundle.js:1:75624) [<root>]
```

My excel version is 1708 (Build 8431.2242) which is greater than the minimum specified version of Version 1704 (Build 8201.2001) or later for the beta api to run:

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets

Comment: Our bad. The Requirement Sets article that you linked to has the wrong version for "1.7 Beta". You need a more recent version. I'll try to get that for you, ASAP.

Comment: Thank you! @RickKirkham. Waiting for your response

Comment: It works for me on build 1805 9320.2001. I think you probably need to be on at least an 1804 nnnn.nnnn build for the data validation APIs to work. You might need to be on Office Insiders to get a build this recent. See https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider?tab=tab-1